# Simple jquery to ignore show/hide div when user clicks a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs. Clicking on the first toggles the second with jquery show when ever a user clicks anywhere on the div 'body' div.

My problem is this, when a user clicks on a link in the 'body' div, the show executes before the link loads. It creates confusion for users who think they missed something on the last page. **Is it possible to create a simple exception for links within the 'body' div?**

```
<div>
      <div class="body">
         <p>Some really good links</p>
         o Example Org: <a href="http://example.org">example.org</a><br>
         o Example Dotcom: <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
      </div>
      <div class="toggle" style="display: none;">
         <p>Some really detailed information here.</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

My javascript is like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  bindToggle;
});

function bindToggle() {
    $(".toggle").hide();
    $(".body").click(function(event) {
        el = $(this).next();
        if (el.is(":visible")) {
            el.hide('fast');
        } else {
            el.show('fast');
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/esJsP/3/

Comment: Just use `$(this).next().toggle('fast');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling event.stopPropagation on click of link in body stops the event from reaching to body. Add below code and check the output:

```
$('.body > a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/esJsP/5/